# .NEXT() = False en consulta SQL y no se a que se deba

Tags: java, sql, base-de-datos, next

Estoy haciendo un programa y en una parte tengo que verificar el nombre registrado en una BD. Desde JAVA hago la consulta para verificar si el nombre que busca se encuentra en una tabla y al comprobar el resultado con .NEXT() me tira el valor "False" Pero al hacer la misma consulta desde WorkBench si me encuentra el registro, y no se a que se deba esto...

```
        CallableStatement getOperarios_OTEnproceso = consulta.prepareCall("{call getOperarios_OTEnproceso(?)}");

        getOperarios_OTEnproceso.setString(1, obj.getStringUser());
        System.out.println(" nombre : " + obj.getStringUser());
        rs1 = getOperarios_OTEnproceso.executeQuery();
        
        rs1.next();

        System.out.println("Valor Consulta : " + rs1.next());
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Consulta desde WorkBench:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola. Según lo que veo en tu código el detalle esta en el primer `rs1.next();` lo que lleva al primer resultado, cuando lo vuelves a llamar en `System.out.println("Valor Consulta : " + rs1.next());` va al siguiente pero al no existir un segundo registro, entonces devuelve falso

Comment: Hola, vale si tienes razón solo tenia un registro en la tabla pero agregue mas y me mostro lo mismo.. no se si conoces otra función similar a `.next()` que me traiga el valor exacto que busco ?

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres saber si la consulta de arrojó o no resultados, lo que puedes hacer es ejecutar:

```
rs1 = getOperarios_OTEnproceso.executeQuery();
if (!rs1.isBeforeFirst()) {    
    System.out.println("No data"); 
}else{ 
    rs1.next();
    System.out.println("Valor Consulta : " + rs1.getString("Operarios"));
}
```

Lo que hacemos es que con `next()` movemos el cursor al primer resultado y de ahí obtenemos el valor de la columna "Operarios"